# Check / Monitor micropython webrepl connections on ESP8266

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, esp8266, micropython

I'm using a ESP8266 with micropython. For script downloading I use webrepl. I would like to monitor the webrepl connections and want to stop the programm execution if there is a webrepl connection established. And after the connection is closed I would like to reset the ESP8266 by machine.reset()
The problem is, I use some micropython IRQs and a parallel webrepl connection and filetransfer eventually causes filesystem crashes.

My question: How do I read the webrepl connections and how may I evaluate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: According to https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/esp8266/modules/webrepl.py the webrepl.client_s variable needs to be checked. The variable can be read from outside of webrepl as soons as you have imported webrepl module.

Some difficulty: In the current implementation the client_s will keep a closed client socket connection for infinity

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can simply call `uos.dupterm()` to find out if the webrepl is connected.

For Example:

```
if (uos.dupterm()):
  print("webrepl is connected")
else:
  print("webrepl is not connected")
```

Comment: Nowadays(v1.19.1) more like this: `prev = uos.dupterm(None)                                                                                                                      uos.dupterm(prev) if(prev):...`. From here: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/extmod/webrepl/webrepl.py#L120